# Automatic pin position on pgfplot when using custom axis

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I'm trying to put automatically label several plots. For this purpose, I just discover the [`pin`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69679/pgfplot-pin-length) option to add it to the plots.

This solution works rather well, and semi-automatically. However, when you redefine the axis (by setting `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax`) the position stops working, as the labels appear in the original position not the clipped one.

So, how can I make the `pin` and `pos` keywords work within the defined axis instead of the original domain?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis plot post/.append style=
        {mark=none}}

\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-10, xmax=10,
  ymin=-10, ymax=10,
  domain=-10:10,
    ]
\addplot {1.690476*x+0.238095} node [pos=1,pin={above left:{$1$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
\addplot {-57.000000*x+-20.000000} node [pos=1,pin={above left:{$2$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
\addplot {-0.590909*x+-0.113636} node [pos=1,pin={above left:{$3$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Custom axis

[image]

No axis defined

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170361/46598) can help, the `restrict y to domain` option restricts drawing the graph instead of just clipping part of it by restricting the axis.

Comment: The problem is that doesn't show the line with extreme values (such as the red plot).

Comment: What do you mean doesn't show the line? If you restrict the y domain to -10:10 it should still show that part of the line, just as setting the `ymin` and `ymax` would. If not then perhaps you should post a question why `restrict y to domain` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your problem with `restrict y to domain` now, with the default amount of samples no data is actually produced in that y-domain. The simplest solution is to manually specify a different x-domain for that function and/or increase the sampling frequency so the plot is visible also with a restricted y-domain.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot post/.append style=
  {mark=none}}

  \begin{axis}[
  restrict y to domain=-10:10,
  domain=-10:10,
  ]
  \addplot {1.690476*x+0.238095} node [pos=1,pin={below right:{$1$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
  \addplot[samples=200,domain=-1:0] {-57.000000*x+-20.000000} node [pos=1,pin={above left:{$2$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
  \addplot {-0.590909*x+-0.113636} node [pos=1,pin={above left:{$3$}},inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]