# Tikz "restrict y to domain" is not working as intended

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line

I'm trying to draw a plot with Tikz. I need to put a label on my line, preferable on the top right corner of the plot and over the line with the same slope.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    restrict y to domain=256:1204,
    xmin=1990,
    xmax=2021,
    ymin=256,
    ymax=1024,
    enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
    xtick={1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize,semithick},
    extra x ticks={1991,1992,1993,1994,1996,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019,2021},
    extra x tick labels={},
    extra x tick style=
    {
        tick label style={red, below, yshift=0.5ex},
        major tick length=0.5ex,
        tick pos= bottom,
        grid=none
    },
    ytick={256,384,512,640,768,896,1024},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize},
    extra y ticks={288,320,352,416,448,480,544,576,608,672,704,736,800,832,864,928,960,992,1024,1056,1088},
    extra y tick labels={},
    extra y tick style=
    {
    tick label style={red, below,yshift=-1ex},
    major tick length=0.5ex,
    tick pos= left,
    grid=none
    },
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Digits},
    grid = major,
]
\addplot +[domain=1990:2020,samples=2] {x-2000)*32+521} node {$x-2000)*32+521$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I use `restrict y to domain=256:1204` the line disappears. I need to set it like 25:2048 to see the line.

[image]

1. How to limit the line so that it stays inside.
2. How to add a label as in the picture.

Comment: You can remove the dot with `no marks`. The line reappears for instance if you increase the samples. However, I do not precisely understand the purpose of `restrict y to domain=256:1204,` since you have also `ymin=256,
    ymax=1024`, which is more restrictive. If you explain the purpose, it is easier to provide you with a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Like in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170345/pgfplots-how-to-display-a-label-next-to-my-plot-when-the-option-clip-true-cut) I want all stay inside. `no marks` fine. sample set to 100, now seems. thanks.

Comment: When I set `ymax=1000` it still goes out of the plot.

Comment: To remove the dot, you can use `\addplot` instead of `\addplot+`...

Comment: With [restrict y to domain] you should try to include at least one point outside the border.  With samples=2, the only point outside the border is the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I wanted to say is that you do not need to use `restrict y to domain=256:1204,` if you have the more restrictive `ymin=256, ymax=1024` in place. You do not need to increase the samples, nor does `restrict y to domain=256:1204,` seem to have any purpose. Just using `no marks` and an appropriate `pos` for the node yields

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}% <- 1.16 would be better
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=1990,
    xmax=2021,
    ymin=256,
    ymax=1024,
    enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
    xtick={1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize,semithick},
    extra x ticks={1991,1992,1993,1994,1996,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019,2021},
    extra x tick labels={},
    extra x tick style=
    {
        tick label style={red, below, yshift=0.5ex},
        major tick length=0.5ex,
        tick pos= bottom,
        grid=none
    },
    ytick={256,384,512,640,768,896,1024},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize},
    extra y ticks={288,320,352,416,448,480,544,576,608,672,704,736,800,832,864,928,960,992,1024,1056,1088},
    extra y tick labels={},
    extra y tick style=
    {
    tick label style={red, below,yshift=-1ex},
    major tick length=0.5ex,
    tick pos= left,
    grid=none
    },
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Digits},
    grid = major,
]
\addplot +[domain=1990:2020,no marks,samples=2] {(x-2000)*32+521} 
node[pos=0.65,sloped,above] {$(x-2000)*32+521$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think there is a typo in your question, you wanted to write `restrict y to domain=256:1024` but wrote `restrict y to domain=256:1204`, right? If you want pgfplots to cut off the plot, you need to increase the samples.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <- 1.16 would be better
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=1990,
    xmax=2021,
    ymin=256,
    ymax=1024,
    restrict y to domain=256:1024,
    enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
    xtick={1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize,semithick},
    extra x ticks={1991,1992,1993,1994,1996,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019,2021},
    extra x tick labels={},
    extra x tick style=
    {
        tick label style={red, below, yshift=0.5ex},
        major tick length=0.5ex,
        tick pos= bottom,
        grid=none
    },
    ytick={256,384,512,640,768,896,1024},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\scriptsize},
    extra y ticks={288,320,352,416,448,480,544,576,608,672,704,736,800,832,864,928,960,992,1024,1056,1088},
    extra y tick labels={},
    extra y tick style=
    {
    tick label style={red, below,yshift=-1ex},
    major tick length=0.5ex,
    tick pos= left,
    grid=none
    },
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Digits},
    grid = major,
]
\addplot +[domain=1990:2020,no marks,samples=201] {(x-2000)*32+521} 
node[pos=0.65,sloped,above] {$(x-2000)*32+521$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, in simple cases like this you could just use `domain=1990:2015.72`, but for more complicated cases an analytical inversion may be more cumbersome (yet then you probably automatically use a large enough number of samples).

Comment: The line starts at x0=1990. Is it possible to cut it for y>1024?

Comment: @kelalaka Sure. The by far simplest solution will be `domain=1990:2015.72`. Do you want a pgfplots solution that does not require you to invert a linear equation?

Comment: Invert :), no. It already does alot. Now fine. Thanks.

Comment: FYI. You can see the final output on Crypto.Se [How big an RSA key is considered secure today?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/18298). Thanks, again.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks! Very interesting!